# confidence interval interpretation for new parameters

Tags: confidence-interval

In the book "all of statistics" the author brings the following interpretation of confidence intervals with the following exmaple:
Interpretation:
"On day 1, you collect data and construct a 95 percent confidence interval for a parameter $\theta_1$. On day 2, you collect new data and construct a 95 percent confidence interval for an unrelated parameter $\theta_2$ . On day 3, you collect new data and construct a 95 percent confidence interval for an unrelated parameter $\theta_3$ . You continue this way constructing confidence intervals for a sequence of unrelated parameters $\theta_1$ ,$\theta_2$ , . . . Then 95 percent of your intervals will trap the true parameter value. There is no need to introduce the idea of repeating the same experiment over and over."
Example:
"Every day, newspapers report opinion polls. For example, they might say that "83 percent of the population favour arming pilots with guns." Usually, you will see a statement like "this poll is accurate to within 4 points.95 percent of the time." They are saying that 83 ± 4 is a 95 percent confidence interval for the true but unknown proportion p of people who favour arming pilots with guns. If you form a confidence interval this way every day for the rest of your life, 95 percent of your intervals will contain the true parameter. ***This is true even though you are estimating a different quantity*** (a different poll question) every day."

can someone explain why this is true? Why can we know 95 percent of the intervals contains the true parameter even though we are estimating a different quantity?

Comment: By construction: each CI is supposed to be based on independent data in this scenario and to cover the true parameter with 95% probability.  (Neither of those is ever truly the case, but that's what the author implicitly supposes.)  The Weak Law of Large Numbers answers your question.

Comment: @whuber I don't understand why if I have the result of a poll on 10 people for president1 on day 1 and then another poll on hamburgers day 2 and then another poll on the number of children on day 3, and so on, why can I use these independent data to get the confidence interval for a new poll on the popularity of movie1? How is this possible? The author says it's true even when we are focusing on a different poll question in each day

Comment: The quotation doesn't assert you can use old, independent data to construct confidence intervals for new data.  It is only making a statement about the long-term rate at which you, as a user of 95% CIs, can expect them to cover their true values, even though in any particular case you will not know whether the value is covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course we need to assume that the model assumptions always hold.

Now consider different $\beta$-level (say $\beta=0.95$) confidence intervals $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ for parameters $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n$. I also assume that the confidence level is precise for all intervals, i.e., $P\{\theta_i\in C_i\}=\beta,\ i=1,\ldots,n$, and that data for all the different intervals are independent.

I can then define binary (0-1) random variables $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ so that $I_i=1$ if $\theta_i\in C_i$, i.e., the confidence interval $i$ catches true parameter $\theta_i$.

This defines an independent sequence of Bernoulli-experiments with probability $\beta$ for observing 1. The relative frequency of successes of the confidence interval then behaves as the standard estimator for a probability $p$ (here equal to $\beta$) in such an experiment, which is the relative frequency of observing 1 (equal to the arithmetic mean of the zeroes and ones). The Laws of Large Numbers then state that this will converge (in probabilistic terms) toward $\beta$ (it will fluctuate around $\beta$ with ever smaller variance for growing $n$).

Comment: then the conclusion is that $\beta$ of the CIs will contain it's respective true parameter $\theta_i$. I am trying to see how this removes the need to introduce the idea of repeating the same experiment over and over. Is it correct to say , for example, true parameter of experiment 1 is in it's CI because this experiment can be one of the 90% experiments who CI contain it's true parameter but how can we compute that probability that experiment 1 is in that 90%? is it that we assume the success for each experiment is equally likely and it's $beta$ @Christian Hennig

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem. Indeed we assume the success for each experiment is equally likely and it's $\beta$ (definition of the level of a CI). I wonder whether your problem is more a philosophical one. You could argue that assuming $P\{\theta_i\in C_i\}=\beta$ as a frequentist probability requires replication of the same experiment. That's a fair point. For me the frequentist definition of probability should be interpreted as "we think of an experiment as if..."-idealisation, rather than this really happening.

Comment: perfect! and yes, I indeed was struggling with the fact that {∈}=  as a frequentist probability requires replication of the same experiment. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Mina This is a general issue with frequentist probability, not with confidence intervals in particular.